# Teach in a university with a master degree

Tags: professorship, job, degree

I don't know if here is the best place to ask that but I'm finishing my master degree in pure mathematics and I would like to travel and know another countries before enter into a doctorate school. In my country with a master degree you can teach in a private university or even in a public university with tenure in small villages or in public universities with 2-years contract in bigger cities.

I would like to know if in your own home country is easy to work in a temporary job as a "professor" or be a permanent professor with tenure in smaller areas with a master degree.

**Remark**

I know that is impossible to teach pure mathematics with only a master degree, but there are a lot of faculties of civil and food engineer, actuarial sciences, computer sciences, etc... which have logic, calculus, linear algebra, etc... courses, i.e., simpler courses with doesn't necessarily need a PHD professor to teach it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you say _in your home country_ are you trying to get information on every country or are there some specific countries you are interested in?

Comment: @earthling I'm trying to get information on every country as possible :)

Answer (score 10):

In the United States, a master's degree typically qualifies you to teach at the junior college or community college level, and also to teach as a lecturer at the university level.  However, you should know that in mathematics there is substantially less supply of these jobs than there is demand for them.  That is, they are hard to find and don't pay very well.

Comment: this is true even in small towns? for example, in my country, in a small town, It just opened right now be a "professor" with tenure with just bachelor.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood your question correctly, you are asking if you can work with your master's degree as an instructor in mathematics while you are touring the world before beginning a doctoral program.

If that is indeed the case, the answer is **maybe**, although it would be very difficult to accomplish.

The reason for this is that you would likely have to surmount visa issues, which can make it difficult for foreign nationals to gain employment in another country. You'd probably have to line up the position *before* you traveled, which would complicate things even further.

However, another thing to keep in mind is that in most universities, the math courses are taught out of the math department—including "service" courses taught for other departments, such as CS, engineering, and physical science. Even in these cases, first priority likely goes to faculty, existing teaching staff, and graduate students within the department. Only if there remains a need for additional teaching staff will they be likely to offer you a contract. And, as Stirling points out, they're unlikely to pay very well. (But then again, I suppose this is just a means of supporting yourself during your travels, in which case this might not be such a bad deal.)

Comment: not necessarily, For example, in Europe the countries are very near to each other, I can be in a particular place and from that place I can travel in the weekends.

Comment: Even in small towns is difficult? for example, in my country, in a small town, It just opened right now be a "professor" with tenure with just bachelor.

Comment: "not necessarily, For example, in Europe the countries are very near to each other": Yes, but first you have to get a job in one of those countries, and this needs to be done _in advance_. You will almost certainly not be able to just show up in Europe and look for jobs.

Comment: "Even in small towns is difficult?" If those countries are in most industrialized nations, and most of the ones in Europe, yes. Again, the job hunt will be made more difficult because you're a foreigner, and therefore will have to go through more hurdles. (In most of Europe, for instance, an employer would likely have to show that you have "unique capabilities" that can't be found in the EU.)

Comment: I'm not concern with this, I have other means to get a visa. Another possibility is do a PHD out there.

Comment: Fine, but the basic answer is that in most Western countries, a tenured position nowadays requires a PhD. Getting around this in most countries simply isn't an option.

Comment: The way you're saying that gives me an impression that even with a PHD I would not have easily even a non-tenured professor position.

Comment: In many countries, yes, that's true. You can be a lecturer, but not a professor. (A professor is normally expected to advise graduate students who will receive PhD's!)

Comment: Do you know which countries I can easily be a lecturer with a PhD? Thank you for your clarifications.